# wamp3: directory listing is 404 in win 10

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I installed wamp3 64 bit with php 5.6.16 and Apache 2.4.17 and MySql 5.7.9 in windows 10.

My problem:

When in a folder (in www folder) not exist index.php (OR index.html) error 404 Occurs and didn't show directories and files list.

My httpd.conf file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14475697/

Error screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,
Create a .htaccess file and put the following directive

```
Options Indexes
```

Follow the link,

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/enabling-apache-file-directory-indexing/